# Assigning Delegates to ViewController Classes

Tags: objective-c, delegates

Following this pattern.

```
// foo.m

Bar* bar = [[Bar alloc] init];
[baz setDelegate:bar];
[bar release];
```

I'm able to call UIImagePicker Delegates in the Bar Class. Specifically, didFinishPickingImage. However, I'm not able to set my the IBOutlet UIImageView myImageView. like.

```
// bar.m

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo

self.myImageView.image = img;
```

When I debug UIImageView, it's nil I think because the UIImage param passed to didFinishPickingImage is also blank.

My question is, why? I am assuming I set my delegate correctly as per this example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a UIImageView to a UIImage.  This might work better:

```
self.myImageView.image = img;
```

Comment: That was just a typo. Mia culpa. The Image passed into the Delegate is still blank.

Comment: Ahh, can you show us where you set your delegate up in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually allocating memory for 'myImageView'?  It isn't shown.  That's not automatic, `myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];` would be needed

Comment: I thought that too, but still nothing.